# UISplitViewController's master rootViewController view too wide

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller

On Xcode's Interface Builder, if I add a UISplitViewController to my storyboard, the width of the view of the rootViewController for the splitViewController's master is larger than the area assigned to it by the split view. That means that any content in the master view is cut off, as it extends out of the bounds of the split view's container.

This happens both for a split view controller that I've tried to integrate into my project, and a brand new split view controller that I've dragged onto the storyboard, as you can see here:

[image: root view controller of split view controller's master exceeds container bounds]

I'm able to reproduce this in new projects on both Xcode 12.5 but also the 13.0 beta 5.

Are others able to reproduce this? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround?

Comment: The rest of us have no such problem, so could you give instructions for doing what you're doing?

Comment: @matt thanks for your reply! In the above screenshot I've just created a new project, entered the storyboard file, clicked "+" in the top right corner, and chosen the UISplitViewController. It's added to the storyboard like as in the screenshot, with a view that's wider than the bounds of the container.

Comment: Cool, I see it on my machine! But that isn't enough to prove that anything bad happens when the app runs. There must be more to it.